# LINQ to SQL Foreign Key Restraint

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

In this code, I have an insert button that will take in the user's input from the textbox and store it in the database. I know the code works as intended with the other tables that have no Foreign Keys in them, but this one does and I'm not sure how to handle it. Everytime it tries to insert CustomerID, the Foreign Key, I keep getting the following error, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Orders_Customers". The conflict occurred in database "northwind", table "dbo.Customers", column 'CustomerID'.

Below is the insert button code and an image of the program running.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Order od = new Order
        {
            OrderID = int.Parse(ordertxt.Text),
            CustomerID = customertxt.Text

        };
        db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(od);
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        display_order();
```

[Program Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxsB7.png)

Comment: This can only happen if you try to insert a non-existing CustomerID. Since that's the only possible cause it shouldn't be hard to figure it out. At any rate, we can't because we don't have your data nor your code.

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are inserting into the CustomerID column does not exist in your Customer table, so it cannot be inserted as a foreign key. You could either add logic to validate the value against the Customer table before inserting, and create a new customer if needed, or alter the column so that it is no longer a foreign key if you do not need it to act as such.

Comment: CustomerID does exist, it is the Primary Key in the Customer Table.

Comment: CustomerID exists, but does that _value_ exist in the Customer table? That's the issue here.